# Reformulate the initial value problem as an equivalent integral equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations, initial-value-problems

Reformulate this initial value problem as an equivalent integral equation.
$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y=x,  \ \ \ \ 0\leq x \leq 1, \ \ \ \ y(0)=1, y'(1)=0 $$

I'm not sure how to do this.
I think I start by letting $\phi=\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ and integrating over $[0,1]$ which gives:
$$y'(1)-y'(0)=\int^1_0 \phi(t) \ dt $$
Then using $y'(1)=0$, this gives:
$$y'(0)=-\int^1_0 \phi(t) \ dt$$

Do I then integrate this over $[0,x]$?

This is one example of a few inital value problems that I'm not sure how to reformulate so is there a method I follow so that I can apply this to the others?

Answer (score 1):

You can use that by partial integration
$$
y(x)=y(0)+y'(0)x+\int_0^x(x-s)y''(s)\,ds
$$
or first transform the second order equation into a first order system and use the usual Picard integral equation.